# Packages not installing on miktex

Tags: errors

I have tried severally to install packages through miktex but each time I try am getting the same error "get host by name failed in tcp_connect()". I have tried restarting the computer but to no avail. This is a new installation of miktex on my PC but I have been using it on the same machine for the past 6 months. Miktex got ininstalled when my PC was with an IT personell who was fixing windows problem.

Am using windows 10.

Please help.

Comment: In the `MikTeX console > Updates screen > Retrieve from: `  try the option  `<Random package repository from the internet> `.